# Restore auth using SecurityContext or Authentication instance in multi threaded environment

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-security, scope, grpc-java

I have an `AuthenticationServerInterceptor` for grpc-java, that authenticates any request. However, the request processing itself is split into multiple threads.

For the sake of simplicity lets assume, that there are 3 parts (that are potentially executed by different threads):

- Establishing the request and doing the authentication
- [1..* times] Processing the parts of the request
- Closing the request

What should I pass to the other places in order to allow me to restore the authenticated context in the later cases? (All three parts belong to a single request and they share a grpc-context)

- The `Authentication` instance
- The `SecurityContext` instance

If I pass along the `Authentication` instance, then I ensure that for each part of the request the original authentication is restored. However, any additional information that might be stored in the (custom) security context will be lost.
If I pass along the `SecurityContext` instance, then I ensure that for each part of the request the additional information and an authentication are passed along, but the developer must be careful with modifying that context.

Unfortunately I couldn't find any information about which to pass along in the docs.

I cannot just decide on either of those, because the authentication process is part of a library and it doesn't know anything about whether there might be additional details in the context and what the developer might do when processing the request parts.

Here is my current implementation, that is tested to be working+thread safe:
https://github.com/yidongnan/grpc-spring-boot-starter/blob/2ee90f16ee4295370ee47c40829805ff1a9f4f51/grpc-server-spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/net/devh/boot/grpc/server/security/interceptors/DefaultAuthenticatingServerInterceptor.java#L59

TLDR: Is spring-security's `SecurityContext` more thread-scoped or more request-scoped?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the default option in Spring Security is thread Local, meaning that if your request create new threads, these new ones will be created with an empty Security context. You can set it to mode Inheritable Thread Local with the following code:

```
@Bean
public MethodInvokingFactoryBean methodInvokingFactoryBean() {
    MethodInvokingFactoryBean methodInvokingFactoryBean = new MethodInvokingFactoryBean();
    methodInvokingFactoryBean.setTargetClass(SecurityContextHolder.class);
    methodInvokingFactoryBean.setTargetMethod("setStrategyName");
    methodInvokingFactoryBean.setArguments(new String[]{SecurityContextHolder.MODE_INHERITABLETHREADLOCAL});
    return methodInvokingFactoryBean;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Unfortunately, the threads aren't created on the spot, but are sourced from a thread pool (netty). Also I don't wish to change the way, spring manages the context. I only want to explicitly set the context/authentication (And I would like to now which to set).